# Explanation of Bizarre Printer Behavior?

Tags: pdf, printing, printer, home-networking, unicode

Today immediately before I closed my laptop, I had printed 2 copies of a PDF file. Then about 2 hours later, I opened my laptop again and the printer started to generate a large pile of mostly blank pages for no apparent reason. However, some of the pages had garbled UTF-8 characters all over them.

For what reason, if any, would my printer be doing this? I can provide specs on the printer, my laptop, or my home network configuration on request if necessary, though none of those have been customized in any special way that I think would be relevant to this.

Comment: I used to see this all the time. Somehow the pdf has printed the text representation of the binary data. I have seen them be hundreds of pages! Not enough information to give you a possible answer as to why it happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy - I bet this is a network attached printer: You closed your laptop while the print job (or some trailing data) was still being sent to the printer - this stopped the transmission.

When you reopened your laptop, it duly went on sending the remaining data, but the printer had in the meantime discarded the half-sent data because of a timeout or disconnection event, so the remainder (binary data) was completely out of context, prompting the printer to try and parse it, which it did with dire consequences.

Comment: I've only ever seen this occur on non-networked printers. Granted, it can still happen on network printers.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Seems weird that there's nothing in the protocol dictating some sort of required pattern at the beginning of the transmission to confirm that it's actually the intended beginning of a stream of data.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, many printers still support an archaic "line printer" mode, where the data is treated as a literal stream of characters to print out.